Rasterio: Gererate GeoTiff Image from a Multipoligon after buffer
After import a raster file and add buffer of 20meters I whant to write a new raster with this dimensions, but getting error:
import rasterio
from rasterio import features
from rasterio import transform
from shapely.geometry import shape, Point, Polygon
import numpy as np
import zipfile,contextlib
from io import BytesIO
from contextlib import ExitStack
#read cloud raster from zip
with zipfile.ZipFile('...img/S2B_MSIL2A_20230926T132239_N0509_R038_T22KHC_20230926T171115.SAFE.zip',"r") as zf_:
zfiledata=BytesIO(zf_.read('S2B_MSIL2A_20230926T132239_N0509_R038_T22KHC_20230926T171115.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T22KHC_A034241_20230926T132553/IMG_DATA/R20m/T22KHC_20230926T132239_SCL_20m.jp2'))
with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
uzFile=stack.enter_context(zf.open('S2B_MSIL2A_20230926T132239_N0509_R038_T22KHC_20230926T171115.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T22KHC_A034241_20230926T132553/IMG_DATA/R20m/T22KHC_20230926T132239_SCL_20m.jp2'))
_uzFileBytes=stack.enter_context(BytesIO(_uzFile.read()))
with rasterio.open(_uzFileBytes) as src_raster:
raster_pixels=src_raster.read(1)
raster_transform=src_raster.transform
raster_meta=src_raster.meta
scl_pixels=raster_pixels.copy()
#detect pixels with cloud and shadow
index_pixels=np.where(np.isin(scl_pixels.astype('float32'),[3,8,9,10]),scl_pixels.astype('float32'),None)
cldsdw_rows,cldsdw_cols=np.where(np.array(index_pixels,dtype=np.float32)>0)
cldsdw_coords = raster_transform(cldsdw_rows,cldsdw_cols)
cldsdw_points = [Point(x, y) for x, y in zip(cldsdw_coords[0], cldsdw_coords[1])]
cldsdw_polygon = Polygon(cldsdw_points)
cldsdw_bufygon = cldsdw_polygon.buffer(20) ##add buffer 20m
cldsdw_features = [{'geometry': shape(geom)} for geom in cldsdw_bufygon.geoms]
with rasterio.open('...img/r20moutput.tif', 'w', *raster_meta) as dst:
rasterio.features.rasterize(cldsdw_features, dst.write, transform=raster_transform)
on write, its getting errors:






...
/opt/.virtualenv/visaopq/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rasterio/features.py:336: ShapeSkipWarning: Invalid or empty shape {'geometry': <POLYGON ((799973.998 7735779.078, 800020 7735793.552, 800020 7735840, 80002...>} at index 0 will not be rasterized.
...
warnings.warn(
/opt/.virtualenv/visaopq/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rasterio/features.py:336: ShapeSkipWarning: Invalid or empty shape {'geometry': <POLYGON ((902849.006 7768146.566, 903497.172 7768350.498, 903239.994 775753...>} at index 21 will not be rasterized.
warnings.warn(
/opt/.virtualenv/visaopq/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rasterio/features.py:336: ShapeSkipWarning: Invalid or empty shape {'geometry': <POLYGON ((903779.055 7780200.043, 903777.76 7780200.126, 903775.841 7780200...>} at index 22 will not be rasterized.
warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
File "/opt/.virtualenv/visaopq/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rasterio/env.py", line 410, in wrapper
return f(*args, **kwds)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/opt/.virtualenv/visaopq/lib/python3.12/site-packages/rasterio/features.py", line 378, in rasterize
if len(out_shape) != 2:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: object of type 'method' has no len()
<<<

Can you edit your post and fix the code, it is full of syntax errors

Code needs to be added from the successfully parsed source, directly into the Question body. No HTML formatting is permitted. Code formatting is performed with the "code" button (which adds four spaces to the whole block, or by using triple backtics (```) above and below the code.

The real issue is probably in the buffered geometry because the error is "ShapeSkipWarning: Invalid or empty shape {'geometry': <POLYGON ((870280.908 7799934.063, ..."

sorry, I dont know how to edit ou delete a post - I post again.
trying to use this place yet.

tankyou, I deleted the 2nd post and edited this, sorry - trying to improve this question

You're not calling rasterize correctly, for one.  You're supplying out_shape=dst.write, which makes no sense.  Check the docs for the signature: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.features.html#rasterio.features.rasterize

I think thats the error, reading manual.



out_shape (tuple or list with 2 integers) – Shape of output numpy.ndarray.



Not possible to write tag as tuple, Tankyou! now trying to convert the poligon on tuples
